# How do I cut these columns out to make this?

Tags: linux, unix

*Unix

The file I'm trying to transform contains:

```
abc.123?zyx
```

I'm trying to transform it to make it like this:

```
123 ZYX abc
```

I used the commands :

```
cut -f1 -d "." $data > first

cut -f2 -d "?" $data > second
```

But, when I can't seem to copy the last column to a new file. 
I also wanted to know how to capitalize the last column I am trying to copy.

Answer (score 4):

I think 'tr' (translate) would be more apt for the first part.
For ex:

```
$> echo "abc.123?zyx" | tr '[.?:]' ' '
abc 123 zyx
```

Now to convert the last column of the resulting string to upper, you can use awk:

```
$> echo "abc 123 zyx" | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " toupper($3) }'
abc 123 ZYX
```

So as a whole following should work for you:

```
$> cat <file> | tr '[.?:]' ' ' | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " toupper($3) }'
```

Comment: There is a small correction in the final answer: `tr '[.?:]' ' ' < <file> | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " toupper($3) }'`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I assumed tr works on file.

Comment: `echo abc.123?zyx | awk '{print $2, toupper($3), $1}' FS='[.?]'`

Answer (score 0):

Could not comment on @Ajay Kumar's answer. I was just about to write the correction `tr '[.?:]' ' ' < <file>` as described by @learningloop.

Also small updation, since OP requires the string as 123 ZYX abc, changing the answer to:

`tr '[.?:]' ' ' < <file> | awk '{print $1 " " toupper($3) " " $2 }'`

Answer (score 0):

Following is a `sed` based solution, if the requirement is to change the file inline:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)?\(.*\)/\2 \U\3 \L\1/g' <file>
```